# Empty python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running a script remotely on a cluster to generate a scatter plot. I wish to save the plot, but I don't want the plot to be display or a window to come up (as when you execute plt.show() ). 
My saved plots are always empty. This is the code that I'm using (below). Any tips would be very helpful. Thanks!

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([-1,maxX+1])    
ax.set_ylim([0,maxY+1])

ax.set_xlabel('Comparison number (n)', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Normalized cross correlation score', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')

ax.scatter(xaxis,yaxis)

plt.savefig('testfig.png')
```

Comment: what are `xaxis` and `yaxis`? hard to diagnose without them.

Comment: and also `maxX` and `maxY`.

Comment: xaxis and yaxis are two lists of the same size with numeric data. e.g., xaxis=[0,1,2,3,4,5], yaxis=[-1.1,2.3,-4,50,3,0]. maxX and maxY are max(xaxis) and max(yaxis0; i.e., the maximum value that occurs along each axis.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use avoid showing plot windows (i.e. to do off-screen rendering) you probably want to use a different `matplotlib` backend.

Before any `matplotlib` `import` statements, add

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

and subsequent calls to `matplotlib` will not show any plot windows.

If your plot file shows an empty axis, then the problem lies in the plotting arguments as calling plot with empty arguments creates an empty axis.